# Android web api call without asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-2.2-froyo

I need to make an api call on click of button. So i do it following way.

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) 
                            {
                                try 
                                {
                                     HttpResponse apiResponse = mySingleTonehttpClient.execute(new HttpGet(Url));
HttpEntity resEntity = apiResponse.getEntity();
InputStream instream = resEntity.getContent();
String result = convertInputStreamToString(instream);

    }
}
```

This code is working fine if i set targetSDKVersion = 8 in Manifest file. But giving me Network mainthread error for targetSDKVersion = 11. Can anyone suggest me what should i do?

Thanks,

Jay

Comment: You have to use asynctask for doing Network related work for higher version.

Comment: Also using asynctask is not a good idea for network operations. They are good for short-lived operations. Use Thread class or other  useful classes in java library such as ThreadPoolExecutor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that you're not supposed to do things that can possible take a long time in the UI Thread. Because doing that will result in the UI being blocked, and you're application will be lagging.

That's why you should either use a [Worker Thread](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#WorkerThreads) or an AsyncTask to do Network IO. You can read more information about how to use them and how they can interact with the UI Thread on the Android Developer guide.

Comment: Hey Chnoch. Got your point but why it is working fine with tagetSDKVersion = 8 and not in 11?

Comment: I haven't found any sources for my assumption, but I guess that Google at some point realized that they are better off if they just enforce this convention. In that way novice developers already start doing things right. And so somewhere in between API 8 and 11 they made using the network (among other things) from a separate thread a necessity.

Comment: So you mean i have to use asynctask or Threads to make http request. BTW i have also tried with Thread as your suggestion here but still getting same issue. So going to use async task here. Thanks for your answer. Jay [Stepin](http://stepin-solutions.com)

Comment: Yeah, as it is now you have to use a different thread. The problem with using a regular Thread is that you can run into different problems, such as that you're not allowed to change anything in the UI from outside the UI Thread. That's why the Android Framework contains certain specific classes such as AsyncTask or Worker Threads to create a usable and good solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should not do networks call on main/UI thread of Application. you may start new worker thread that will run in separate thread rather than on UI thread.